# What's the difference between these two object instantiation approaches?

Tags: c++

Suppose I have a class named A:

```
Class A
{
...
}
```

And what's the difference between the following 2 approaches to instanciate an object:

```
void main(void)
{
    A a;  // 1
    A *pa=new A();  // 2
}
```

As my current understanding (not sure about this yet):

- Approach 1 allocate the object a on the stack frame of the main() method, and so this object cannot deleted because that deletion doesn't make sense (don't know why yet, could someone explain that?).
- Approach 2 allocate the object a on the heap of the process and also a A* vairable *pa* on the stack frame of the main() method, so the object can be deleted and and the pa can be assigned null after the deletion.

Am I right? If my understanding is correct, could someone tell me why i cannot delete the *a* object from the stack in approach 1?

Many thanks...

Comment: Please change `void main(void)` to `int main()`.

Comment: Yes.  Generally, you don't want to write function(void) {}.  This is considered bad syntax by many authorities:
http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/newbie.html#faq-29.4

Answer (score 6):

Object `a` has *automatic* storage duration so it will be deleted automatically at the end of the scope in which it is defined. It doesn't make sense to attempt to delete it manually. Manually deletion is only required for objects with *dynamic* storage duration such as `*pa` which has been allocated using `new`.

Answer (score 4):

1. The objects live time is limited to
   the scope the variable is defined
   in, once you leave the scope the
   object will be cleaned up. In c++ a
   scope is defined by any Block
   between { an the corresponding }.
2. Here only the pointer is on the stack and not the object, so when
   you leave the scope only the pointer
   will be cleaned up, the object will
   still be around somewhere.

To the part of deleting an object, delete not only calls the destructor of your object but also releases its memory, this would not work as the memory management of the stack is automated by the compiler, in contrast the heap is not automated and requires calls to new and delete to manage the live time of an object.
Any object created by a call to new has to be deleted once, forgetting to do this results in an memory leak as the objects memory will never be released.

Answer (score 1):

Approach 1 declared a variable and created an object. In Approach 2, you created an instance and pointer to it.

**EDIT** : In approach 1, the object will go out of scope and will be automatically deleted. In approach 2, the pointer will be automatically deleted, but not what it is pointing to. That will be your job.

Comment: Err, no, the default constructor is called.

Comment: hi, fastcodejava, thanks for your reply. this is C++ syntax, not C#. Approach 1 does create an object instance. Cause I can access its memeber variables.

Comment: @smwikipedia - I agree, I typed too fast. Corrected the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Allocation does two things:

1) Allocates memory for the object

2) Calls the constructor on the allocated memory

Deletion does two things:

1) Calls the destructor on the object

2) Deallocates the memory used by the destructed object

When you allocate on the stack (`A a;`), you're telling the compiler "please make an object for me, by allocating memory, then call the constructor on that memory.  And while you're at it, could you handle calling the destructor and freeing the memory, when it goes out of scope?  Thanks!".  Once the function (main) ends, the object goes out of scope, the destructor is called, and the memory is freed.

When you allocate on the heap (`A* pa = new A();`), you're telling the compiler "please make an object for me.  I know what I'm doing, so don't bother calling the destructor or freeing the memory.  I'll tell you when to do it, some other time".  Once the function (main) ends, the object you allocated stays in scope, and is not destructed or freed.  Hopefully you have a pointer to it stored somewhere else in your program (as in, you copied pa to some other variable with a bigger scope).  You're gonna have to tell the compiler to destruct the object and free the memory at some point in the future.  Otherwise, you get a memory leak.

Simply put, the "delete" command is only for objects allocated on the heap, because that's the manual memory management interface in C++ - new/delete.  It is a command for the heap allocator, and the heap allocator doesn't know anything about stack allocated objects.  If you try to call delete on a stack allocated object, you might as well have called it on a random memory address - they're the same thing as far as the heap allocator is concerned.  Very much like trying to access an object outside array bounds:

```
int a[10];
std::cout << a[37] << "\n"; // a[37] points at... ? no one knows!
```

It just isn't meant to do that :)

Edit:
P.S. Memory leaks are more important when you are allocating memory in a function other than `main`.  When the program ends, leaked memory gets deallocated, so a memory leak in main might not be a big deal, depending on your scenario.  However, destructors never get called on leaked objects.  If the destructor does something important, like closing a database or a file, then you might have a more serious bug on your hands.

Comment: Technically, the object does not exist prior to the constructor's completion. The constructor makes an object out of raw memory. If the constructor throws an exception, there never even was an object.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine stack as `void* stack = malloc(1.000.000);`
Now, this memory block is managed internally by the compiler and the CPU.
It is a shared piece of memory. Every function can use it to store temporary objects there.

That's called *automatic storage*. You cannot  delete parts of that memory because its purpose is
to be used again again.  If you explicitly delete memory, that memory returns back to the system,
and you don't want that to happen in a shared memory.

In a way, automatic objects are also get *deleted*. When an object gets out of scope the compiler places
an *invisible* call to object's destructor and the memory is available again.

Comment: Thanks Nick. So the stack is "planned" at compile time and keeps occupied by the program through its lifetime, while the heap can be requested and released at runtime. If so, what if the stack size is not large enough? could its size be adjusted at runtime?

Comment: @smwikipedia, indeed, plus the code runs in a *thread*. Usually each thread has its own stack. If you explicitly create a thread you can set it's stack size. On Windows see, for example, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: ... also compilers have the option to set application's default stack size. Since the stack has fixed size, a stack overflow can happen: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow

Answer (score 1):

You cannot delete objects on the stack because it's implemented in memory exactly that way -- as a stack. As you create objects on the stack, they are added on top of each other. As the objects leave scope, they are destroyed from the top, in the opposite order they were created in (add to the top of the stack, and remove from the top of the stack). Trying to call `delete` on something in the stack would break that order. The analogy would be like trying to pull some paper out of the middle of a stack of papers.

The compiler controls how objects are created and removed on the stack. It can do this because it knows exactly how large each object on the stack is. Since the stack size is set at compile time, it means that allocating memory for things on the stack is extremely fast, much faster than allocating memory from the heap, which is controlled by the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

stack memory is not being managed on the same way as heap memory.
there is no point to delete objects from stack: they will be deleted
automatically upon end of scope/function.